Jenkins Jira Pipeline Steps - Concurrent update of issue removes versions
I have a case, where a Jenkins pipeline uses the code (https://jenkinsci.github.io/jira-steps-plugin/getting-started/examples/append_fix_version/)
node {
    stage('JIRA') {
        def searchResults = jiraJqlSearch jql: "project = ${jiraProjectKey} AND issuekey = ${issueKey}'"
        def issues = searchResults.data.issues
        for (i = 0; i <issues.size(); i++) {
            def result = jiraGetIssue idOrKey: issues[i].key
            def newVersion = jiraNewVersion version: [name: "${newVersion}",
                                                project: "${jiraProjectKey}"]
            def fixVersions = result.data.fields.fixVersions << newVersion.data
            def testIssue = [fields: [fixVersions: fixVersions]]
            response = jiraEditIssue idOrKey: issues[i].key, issue: testIssue
        }
    }
}

The code finds the issue, creates the version and then appends it to the issue.
We have a case, where an update spawns concurrent jobs to build that will update the same Jira issue with different versions. What we have found is randomly each executing build will remove another builds append version.

Job 1 - build 1 - Update ${issueKey} fixVersion 1.1
Job 2 - build 1 - Update ${issueKey} fixVersion 2.1
Job 3 - build 1 - Update ${issueKey} fixVersion 3.1

In the end the supplied ${issueKey} will sometimes have lost fixVersions. For example, in the above it may end up with the fixVersion of the ${issueKey} as 1.1 and 3.1. The issues activity history would show that 2.1 was removed.
We are confident this is a Dirty Write problem with either Jira or the Jenkins Plugin. I would think Jira having multiple users updating the same issue simultaneously with different versions would not replace the others version (have not test this).
My question is, anyone have any ideas how to update the above pipeline script to handle the case of independent pipeline executions that happen to run at the same time, so it will only append to the fixVersion?
Lastly, I'm trying to develop a standalone job to consistently induce this case so I can better test any solutions but I have yet to complete it.
Thanks in advance.
Steve

I was successful in creating a pipeline that would induce this issue and then found a workable solution. This full pipeline code is below.
def tasks = [:]
tasks["Ver1"] = {
    jiraUpdate( "Test-Concurrent-Issue-1.1")
}
tasks["Ver2"] = {
    jiraUpdate( "Test-Concurrent-Issue-2.1")
}
tasks["Ver3"] = {
    jiraUpdate( "Test-Concurrent-Issue-3.1")
}
 
node {
  parallel tasks
}
 
def jiraUpdate(String version) {

   stage( version ) {
      def jiraProjectKey="TEST"
      def jiraIssue='TEST-1234'

      def newVersion = jiraNewVersion version: [name: "${version}", project: "${jiraProjectKey}"]
      def searchResults = jiraJqlSearch jql: ("issuekey = " + jiraIssue)
      def issues = searchResults.data.issues

      for( i = 0; i <issues.size( ); i++ ) {

        def result = jiraGetIssue idOrKey: issues[i].key

        // def fixVersions = result.data.fields.fixVersions << newVersion.data
        // def testIssue = [fields: [fixVersions: fixVersions]]
        // jiraEditIssue idOrKey: issues[i].key, issue: testIssue

        withCredentials([usernameColonPassword(credentialsId: '${credential}', variable: 'CRED')]) {
          sh """
              curl --request PUT \
                 -u ${CRED} \
                 --data '
                  {
                      "update": {
                          "fixVersions": [
                              {"add": 
                                  {"name": "${version}"}
                              }
                          ]
                      }
                  }' \
                 -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
                 ${jiraURL}/rest/api/2/issue/${jiraIssue}
            """
        }
      }
   }
}

The 3 commented out lines was the original code from the link provided in the question. What I found is that Jira actually doesn't handle this case. Load two web pages with the same issue. In each edit the fix version to bind a unique version.  Click save on the first page, then save the second page without refreshing. You'll see that the second pages version is on the issue and the history shows the first version was removed.
I did some research into the REST API and apparently the Jira REST API (https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Software-questions/Using-REST-to-set-fixVersions/qaq-p/1642952) supports updating the fixVersion with an add/remove option. The above test code show the update with add. This seems to handle properly concurrent writes to the fix version and does not mess with other data.
While the pipeline code is much more complex it does now work.
If the maintainers of the Jenkins Jira Pipeline plugin could look at adding a advancement to the jiraEditIssue path this might be nice.
Best of luck and hope this helps someone else in the future.
